# Configuring roll'n api

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine, laminas-api-tools

I jumped onto this tutorial: [***installing roll'n api link***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21932941/apigility-rolln-api-windows-quick-install-guide/27008084#27008084) 
for installing **roll'n api** (extended framework based from **apigility** framework with **doctrine 2** orm)

However I had a problem on steps 4 and 5.

> C:\www\api>php public\index.php build api module
>
> C:\www\api>php public\index.php build api

When I issue the above commands, it fails.

This was what was prompted in my Windows command line:

> Reason for failure: Invalid arguments or no arguments provided

I also went directly to the roll'n api home page:
[***roll'n api homepage link***](http://rollnapi-tomanderson.rhcloud.com/) 
The problem there is running **~/bin/install** and **~/bin/rebuild**. Since there are no /bin folder with install and rebuild .php files.

Thanks!

Comment: What commands you have passed in your windows command line??

Comment: Hi Indrasinh Bihola, have you checked the tutorial link? anyway, these commands:

C:\www\api>php public\index.php build api module
C:\www\api>php public\index.php build api

Comment: Have you generated `doctrine entities`?

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola yes i have generated the entities successfully, I only got stucked in steps 4 and 5.